# Как мне организовать, чтобы функция start вызывала функцию input2 (брала значение- guess) и записывала его рядом с тексом?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Чтение и запись")

def start():
    phrase="Номер:"
    output.insert(tk.END, f'{phrase}\n')

def input2():
        guess = txt.get()
        output.insert(tk.END, f'{guess}\n')
        txt.delete(0, 3)
        
#Первая кнопка
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Начать!", font=15, command=start)  
btn1.pack()

#read number from entry and write to text 
txt = tk.Entry(root, width=10)  
txt.pack()

#вторая кнопка
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="Принять", command = input2)
btn2.pack()

#вывод в текст
global output
output = tk.Text(root, width=49, height = 13, wrap = tk.WORD)
output.pack()
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вызовите ее внутри своей функции и все.

Comment: А как именно? Так:                                                                                                                             `def start():
    phrase="Номер:"
    output.insert(tk.END, f'{phrase}\n')
    def input2(guess):
          guess = txt.get()
           output.insert(tk.END, f'{guess}\n')
            txt.delete(0, 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mr. Thekotik, Если я правильно Вас понял то можно так:

```
def start():
    phrase = "Номер:"
    output.insert(tk.END, f'{phrase} {input2(but="start")}\n')


def input2(but=''):
    guess = txt.get()
    if but =='start':
        return guess
    else:
        output.insert(tk.END, f'{guess}\n')
        txt.delete(0, 3)
```

Если хотите, чтобы очистка была, то добавьте `delete`:

```
def start():
    phrase = "Номер:"
    output.insert(tk.END, f'{phrase} {input2(but="start")}\n')


def input2(but=''):
    guess = txt.get()
    if but =='start':
        txt.delete(0, 3)
        return guess
    else:
        output.insert(tk.END, f'{guess}\n')
        txt.delete(0, 3)
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что когда нажимаю кнопку "начать", вызывается функция "start", а в конце работы обращается к функции input2, где я ввожу цифру. Просто я написал игру горячо-холодно (все работает в консоли), написал графическое приложение, а вот как соединить эти 2 проекта я не знаю...

Comment: ``while True:
        secretNum = getSecretNum()
        print('Итак, я загадал число. У вас есть %s попыток, чтобы отгадать его.' % (MAX_GUESS))

        guessesTaken = 1
        while guessesTaken <= MAX_GUESS:
            guess = ''
            while len(guess) != NUM_DIGITS or not isOnlyDigits(guess):
                print('Попытка №%s: ' % (guessesTaken))
                guess = input()
            print(getClues(guess, secretNum))
            guessesTaken += 1
            if guess == secretNum:
                break
            if guessesTaken > MAX_GUESS:``

Comment: print('Попыток больше не осталось. Я загадал число %s.' % (secretNum))

Comment: print('Хотите сыграть еще раз? (да или нет)')
    if not input().lower().startswith('д'):
        break

Comment: Можно с Вами связаться где-нибудь? Мне действительно нужна помощь, очень хочу разобраться. Могу даже оплатить данную услугу. Просто уже все сделано, осталось соединить консольное приложение (программа работает, все алгоритмы есть) и графическое.

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку "Старт"  Вы вызовите функцию start(), которая в месте вызова вызовет input2(but="start") и передаст ей аргумент в виде строки  "start" - в принципе туда хоть что можно поставить , т.к. это всего-лишь аргумент в зависимости от которого Ваша ф-ция будет ф-цией или процедурой